# Можно ли разделить одно любое целое число int на два одинаковых int ? и если да. то как?

Tags: java, scanner, int

Сразу хотел бы извинится задаю свой первый вопрос и только начинаю изучать Java. Поставленная задача должна проверять числа не являются ли они палиндромами считывая их со Scanner. понимаю что на это есть формулы. Но можно ли например с числа 3003 разделив его на int1 = 30; int2 = 03; потом сравнить их оператором if ? еще раз извините если чушь :)

Comment: `int2 = 03` и `int2 = 3` это технически одно и то же число, так что да, в таком виде это чушь. Лучше забудьте про числа и проверяйте палиндром как обычную строку `"3003"`

Comment: можно. считать его как строку из 4 знаков. разбить на 2 строки по 2 знака. каждую строку перевести в Int. (хотя палиндромы как раз через строку, а не через Инт делаются).

Comment: Спасибо Большое за ответы! я постараюсь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте этот код:

```java
String numberStr = String.valueOf(number); // Преобразуем число в строку
int int1 = Integer.parseInt(numberStr.substring(0, 2));
int int2 = Integer.parseInt(numberStr.substring(2);
```